# Bluetooth Scanner with Python Support (Windows 10)

Tags: python, bluetooth, windows-10, barcode-scanner

I'm working on developing a Inventory / POS Management software. I'm developing this in Python using PyQt5. I've been looking for a Barcode Scanner that works with Python in a Windows 10 environment. Ideally, I'm looking for one that includes a way for me to:

- Check battery life for the scanner,
- Is Bluetooth compatible,
- As well as be able to detect when a scan occurs (if possible, when the button itself is being pressed (not just knowing via the influx of characters representing the barcode scanned)).

I've been looking everywhere, but I can't seem to find something that fits the bill. I've seen that the closest seems to be Zebra scanners, but even then, I'm having difficulty ascertaining if it can indeed fulfil those requirements. Are there any bluetooth Barcode Scanner options out there that can do those?

Thank you for your time and assistance,
Kevin

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because HW recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I apologize - I honestly did not know that this is off-topic here. Do you have a recommendation on where I might repost this question?

Comment: You might want to try [hardwarerecs.se]. It looks like it may be on-topic there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I'll do that then.